# How can I embed a "New Item" or "Edit Item" form on a SharePoint online page?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I can get the link to the form, but I want to embed it in a modenern page which contains other content.

I tried adding a link item, but that only creates an external link to the page. I would like something like an embedded iFrame.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found an answer.  You can actually create your own iFrame using the following template, making sure to set custom values for the following elements:

- id: create a unique ID for the form
- src: set this to the URL Of the New Item or Edit Item form page.

Here is the iFrame code template that you can modify and insert:

```
<iframe
width="100%"
height="100%"
id="<make this a unique ID name for the iFrame>"
title="Form "
onload="window.parent.scrollTo(0,0)"
allowtransparency="true"
allowfullscreen="true"
allow="geolocation; microphone; camera"
src="https://<link to your sharepoint new item or edit item form>"
frameborder="0"
style="
min-width: 100%;
height:800px;
border:none;"
scrolling="no"
>
</iframe>
```

And then just plug this code into the page as an embedded iFrame like any other.  This allows you to embed the form into the page along with other content on that page.